# How do I make my chat application continuous?

Tags: java, networking, chat

I have to make a chat application that is able to chat continuously back and forth between the server and the client. I have it so that the server and the client can send one message at a time, but I am not sure how to edit my code so that you can send multiple messages at a time. Also, I need to be able to run this on two separate computers, and I think I have my code set up accurately for this, but I am not sure. Verification for this and an answer to the first question would be appreciated. My code for each class is below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatServer{

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket acceptSocket;
    private PrintStream output;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatServer server = new ChatServer();
        server.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
            acceptSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            output = new PrintStream(acceptSocket.getOutputStream());
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(acceptSocket.getInputStream()));

            while(acceptSocket.isConnected()) {
                String message = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);

                String reply = scan.nextLine();
                output.println(reply);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ChatClient{

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintStream output;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);

            output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            output.println("Connected to Server");

            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while(clientSocket.isConnected()) {
            String message = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);

            String reply = scan.nextLine();
            output.println(reply);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SocketIO for Java is my suggestion. It does what you need it to in what will likely end up being less code and the documentation on it is superb with lots of examples. There is even an Android app demo that uses it for peer-to-peer chat.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java